# In R, how to produce an array containing sorted index of corresponding elements in another array?

Tags: r, sorting

In R, given an numeric array, how to produce another array which contains sorted index order into the original array? To clarify my question, consider an example: For an original array:

```
[33 11 55 22 44]
```

I want to produce another array:

```
[3 1 5 2 4]
```

Each element in the second array indicates sorted index of corresponding element in the first array.

In MATLAB, this can be done by using [B,XI]=sort(A); where XI is the wanted array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the rank() function, found [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rank.html).

Comment: +1 : I didn't know of `rank` function... I would have done `order(order(x))` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I obtained a strange result when I tried rank() on the fourth column of "iris" data. I expected all results to be integers but instead I got some x.5 values. Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Well, I figured out why. Thanks again.